# How photo and lens looks with 1mm focal length?

Tags: lens, focal-length, fisheye

Are there lens with `1mm` focal length?
What is the shortest focal length possible for full frame sensor? And can it be rectilinear lens?

There is `Sigma EX 4,5mm`, but it's for APS-C and still far from 1mm and it's fisheye lens, not rectilinear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Largely it depends on sensor size. 4.5mm is for APS-C but there are shorter ones, even less than 1mm, for smaller sensors.

The issue for a rectilinear lens is that as the angle-fo-view gets wider, the construction becomes more and more difficult. Remember that a rectilinear lens must preserve straight lines and so the optics will get more complex and certainly larger and heavier to correct for aberrations.

At this time, the largest field-of-view from a rectilinear lens on an APS-C camera is 104°, obtainable by at the widest of a Sigma 8-16mm lens. This was the widest of any rectilinear lens until last year when Irix introduced their 11mm and Canon followed with the EF 11-24mm F/4L that can achieve 126° field of view.

With a fisheye, the mapping is completely different and you can have some than even project more than 180°, up to 220° as far as I know, although I forget who was the manufacturer. It is a third-party one.

Comment: The 11-24 reached market before Irix' 11mm lens.  The widest FoV in a single lens is 360 x 60 degrees.  Commercially, there are 270 and 290 degree fisheyes for u4/3.

Comment: That's pretty cool! Although the 4:1 aspect-ratio must be hard to work with.

Comment: Anyone doing 360 degree single-capture imaging is prepared for a little headache :)

Answer (score 1):

I you're talking about "full frame" there is the Nikon 6 mm fisheye (https://www.mir.com.my/rb/photography/companies/nikon/nikkoresources/fisheyes/6mmf28.htm) and the rectilinear Voigtländer 10 mm for Leica M mount: https://voigtlaender.com/10-mm-f-5%2c6-hyper-wide-heliar-vm.html

Comment: How does this answer the question? Seems like a decent comment right now

Comment: I agree, but I don't have comment privileges yet. :)